# Meaning of "wherein I had a great Facility by the Strength of my Memory"

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning

> Having therefore consulted with my Wife, and some of my Acquaintance, I determined to go again to Sea. I was Surgeon successively in two Ships, and made several Voyages, for six Years, to the East and West-Indies; by which I got some Addition to my
> Fortune. My Hours of Leisure I spent in reading the best Authors,
> ancient and modern; being always provided with a good Number of
> Books; and when I was ashore, in observing the Manners and Dispositions of the People, as well as learning their Language; **wherein I had a great Facility by the Strength of my Memory.**

One of the meaning of the "Facility" is "Talent" but I don't think here it is in this meaning.

Dose the whole phrase in bold mean: because of my good memory I easily learned many things?

Source: Gulliver's Travels

Comment: No, facility is not talent. It is the ease with which someone does something.

Comment: @Lambie "the ease with which someone does something" is a reasonable definition of "talent."

Comment: @phoog The facility one has to do something may not be a talent.

Answer (score 1):

Let me transcribe that into simpler English.

> Having therefore consulted with my wife, and some of the people I know, I decided to go back on a ship to sail. I was a surgeon on two ships, back-to-back, and traveled for six years to the East and West Indies, which gave me some wealth in the process. I spent my free time reading books by the best authors, old and new; and was always provided with a good number of books; and when I was on land, in studying the culture of the local people, as well as learning their language; in which I had a great advantage due to my good memory.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I would say _which I found easy because of my good memory_.

Comment: Lot of thanks, you mean: because of my good memory I learn easily. Am I right?